# Grouped pandas dataframe from nested list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a nested list in this format `mydata=[[01/01/20,['point1','point2','point3,...]],[02/01/20,['point1','point2','point3']],...]` I want to create a pandas dataframe grouped by date with every point as a different row.
I have tried manually adding each row through a for loop, but other than taking more than an hour, the dataframe ended up being empty.
Not sure how to go about this. Can I create the grouped dataframe directly from the list?

My desired output would be:

```
    date          points

    01/01/20      point1
                  point2
                  point3
    02/01/20      point1
                  point2
                  point3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output is not fully clear, but if I guess correctly:

```
mydata = [['01/01/20',['point1','point2','point3']],
          ['02/01/20',['point1','point2','point3']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(mydata))
```

Or:

```
cols, data = zip(*mydata)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*data), columns=cols)
```

output:

```
  01/01/20 02/01/20
0   point1   point1
1   point2   point2
2   point3   point3
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! How would I be able to pivot it so that I have it stacked with the dates on the left and points as individual rows on the right?

Comment: @Mary why don't you provide the exact explicit output in your question for clarity? ;)

Comment: Maybe you simply want `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(mydata), orient='index')`?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question to show what output I'm looking for

Comment: OK, then `pd.DataFrame(dict(mydata)).melt()` or `pd.DataFrame(dict(mydata)).stack()`

Comment: Thank you, one more thing, I get the error 'all arrays must be of the same length' because the number of points is different for each sublist. How can I go around it?

Comment: Try: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(mydata), orient='index').unstack()` (untested, I'm AFK)

Comment: I just tried it and with my data structure it works with ```.stack()``` instead of ```.unstack()``` at the end. Thank you again!